# Is there a way to programmatically change the value of a UIStepper based on a calculation?

Tags: ios, uistepper

Let's say I have 3 `UIStepper`s.
When I change the value of one, the values of the other steppers change based on a formula.

Stepper one value is 10.
Stepper two value is 5.
Stepper three value is 3.

If I change stepper 10 +/- 1, it might change the value in stepper two +/- one.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

It is absolutely possible.

You can imagine this scenario:

```
UIStepper *stepperOne = [[UIStepper alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[stepperOne addTarget:self action:@selector(stepperOneChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

- (void)stepperOneChanged:(UIStepper*)stepperOne{
    //This method would be called on the target of your first stepper on UIControlEventsValueChanged

    //Decrease the value by 1
    stepperTwo.value --;

    //OR
    //Increase the value by 1
    stepperTwo.value ++;
}
```

Comment: can I say stepperTwo.value = 10; for example, as my test's come back as NULL.
    
    workOutLength = classLength - (warmUpLength + coolDownLength);
    stepperWorkOutLength.value = workOutLength;  (How the heck do add code to a reply, every time I hit enter it updates the post :(

Comment: you can put it in between two: ` What is returning NULL? And Yes, you can set the value to nay value between the minimum and maximum value

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 4.2

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let stepper = UIStepper(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 200, width: 0, height: 0))
    stepper.wraps = true
    stepper.autorepeat = true
    stepper.maximumValue = 20
    stepper.addTarget(self, action: #selector(stepperValueChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    view.addSubview(stepper)
 }


@objc func stepperValueChanged(_ stepper: UIStepper) {
    print("Chnaged Value: \(stepper.value)")
    stepper.value += 2
    print("Chnaged Value: \(stepper.value)")
    
}
```